# Making Visual C++ DLL from C++ class

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dynamic-linking

I have the following C++ code to make dll (Visual Studio 2010).

```
class Shape {
public:
  Shape() {
    nshapes++;
  }
  virtual ~Shape() {
    nshapes--;
  };
  double  x, y;   
  void    move(double dx, double dy);
  virtual double area(void) = 0;
  virtual double perimeter(void) = 0;
  static  int nshapes;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) Circle : public Shape {
private:
  double radius;
public:
  Circle(double r) : radius(r) { };
  virtual double area(void);
  virtual double perimeter(void);
};

class __declspec(dllexport) Square : public Shape {
private:
  double width;
public:
  Square(double w) : width(w) { };
  virtual double area(void);
  virtual double perimeter(void);
};
```

I have the __declspec,

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Circle
```

I could build a dll with the following command

```
CL.exe /c example.cxx
link.exe /OUT:"example.dll" /DLL example.obj
```

When I tried to use the library,

```
Square* square; square->area()
```

I got the error messages.
What's wrong or missing?

```
example_unittest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual double __thiscall
...
Square::area(void)" (?area@Square@@UAENXZ)
```

### ADDED

Following wengseng's answer, I modified the header file, and for DLL C++ code, I added

```
#define XYZLIBRARY_EXPORT
```

However, I still got errors.

### SOLVED

For main program that links example.dll, I didn't link example.lib.

```
cl /MD /EHsc gtest_main.cc example_unittest.cc /I"./include" /link /libpath:"./lib" /libpath:"." gtest_md.lib example.lib /out:gtest_md_release.exe
```

With the addition, everything works fine.

Comment: I thought DLLs had to use C calling conventions, meaning no C++ member functions. That's just off the top of my head, though.

Comment: How did you import the class Circle at CL.exe?

Comment: You can export C++ classes in DLL interfaces. The problem is that C++ name mangling is applied to exported symbols. Since there is no standard for name mangling, every compiler does it differently. Sometimes different versions of the same compiler will do it differently. This is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In DLL, i suggest to add a macro, and add XYZLIBRARY_EXPORT in pre-processor:

```
#if defined(XYZLIBRARY_EXPORT) // inside DLL
#   define XYZAPI   __declspec(dllexport)
#else // outside DLL
#   define XYZAPI   __declspec(dllimport)
#endif  // XYZLIBRARY_EXPORT

class XYZAPI Circle
```

It will export the Circle class.

In EXE, import the Circle class, without adding pre-processor, as it will import the class by default.

Comment: This seems the most likely cause of the compiler errors.  The compiler probably thinks it should be exporting the DLL classes instead of importing them from a .lib

Answer (score 2):

You must export the Shape class to resolve "static  int Shape::nshapes" error (and maybe the other errors as well).

Don't forget to link the library (example.lib) generated with the DLL

Comment: @prosseek: with the build of yor dll a lib-file is generated. This lib-file must be linked into your test-program

Comment: That's correct, and that was the solution to my added question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of exporting a C++ class directly in a DLL, you could expose a factory function which uses the C calling convention and avoid name mangling issues.

```
class Shape {
  ...
};

class Circle : public Shape {
  ...
};

extern "C" Circle* newCircle();

extern "C" void deleteCircle(Circle* p);
```

The DLL's user can then call newCircle() to create a Circle object, do whatever it needs to do with it and then call deleteCircle() on it to get rid of it. You can't just call delete on the returned pointer because the DLL may not be linking against the same instance of the C++ runtime library as the DLL's user.